# Filter RDD of key/value pairs based on value equality in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, filter, pyspark, rdd

Given

```
[('Project', 10),
 ("Alice's", 11),
 ('in', 401),
 ('Wonderland,', 3),
 ('Lewis', 10),
 ('Carroll', 4),
 ('', 2238),
 ('is', 10),
 ('use', 24),
 ('of', 596),
 ('anyone', 4),
 ('anywhere', 3),
```

in which the value of the paired RDD is the word frequency.

I would only like to return the words that appear 10 times. 
Expected output

```
 [('Project', 10),
   ('Lewis', 10),
   ('is', 10)]
```

I tried using

```
rdd.filter(lambda words: (words,10)).collect()
```

But it still shows the entire list. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your lambda function is wrong; It should be

```
rdd.filter(lambda words: words[1] == 10).collect()
```

---

For example,

```
my_rdd = sc.parallelize([('Project', 10), ("Alice's", 11), ('in', 401), ('Wonderland,', 3), ('Lewis', 10)], ('is', 10)]

>>> my_rdd.filter(lambda w: w[1] == 10).collect()
[('Project', 10), ('Lewis', 10), ('is', 10)]
```